# Display multiple node edit forms on one page with one submit button

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there a module allowing to edit nodes as a list, like in a spreadsheet, not one by one? For example, display a list of nodes on a page (e.g. 100 nodes) with each node having input boxes instead of displayed fields, or a mixture of both. Each input box is associated with a field, if the field has value then this value is already inserted in the input box and available for editing. After making changes press "Save" and it would update all those nodes with relevant field values. It's like editing a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Views and Editable Fields. You then create a page view with the Editable fields for the nodes and your all set. Keep in mind load times and performance by narrowing down the number of WYSIWYG fields and reference fields.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that as well as other modules that google displayed together with Editable Fields (it's Editable Views and Quickedit as of now).